# Filter and search in list using ajax with php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
  <div id="one">  
  <label for="default">Without Ajax</label>
  <input type="text" id="default" list="lang" placeholder="Select">

  <datalist id="lang">
  <option value="English">
  <option value="German">
  <option value="French">

  </option>

 </datalist>
 </div>
```

How to convert this coding to ajax with php. When I press a key on the text, i have to find the match in the list and display all the matches in the text.

Comment: Where are your attempt(s)? People don't just dump a little source code and request others to "convert" it. This isn't a free programming service at your request. Hire a developer if you aren't willing to take the time and effort to try something yourself.

Comment: I am totally agree with NewToJS and i have put the answer which will only guide you to achieve what you want not the exact one of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already know how to retrieve data from mysql database using Php. And basic knowledge of using Jquery.

First thing that you need to do is to import Jquery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jq.js"></script>
```

Then create an input box. Where the user will input his query:

```
<input type="text" id="inp" name="inp"/></span>
```

Then create a div which we will use later to display the results:

```
<div class="results"></div>
```

Declare another script on the head portion of your project:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Inside the new script that you’ve just created. Declare a function that would listen to the keyup event.

```
$(function(){

    $(#inp).keyup(function(){

    });

});
```

Here’s what happens. The function that you have declared will monitor any changes to the input box which has the id ‘inp’. And every time you hit any key on the keyboard. The action which is to be performed inside that event will be executed.

Inside the keyup function. Declare a variable that would store the value which is inputted in the input box.

var inpvalue= $('#inp').val();

Next thing that you need to do, is to declare another jquery function. This is the most important part of this tutorial, since this will be the one who will actually fetch the value from the database.

Then all you have to do now is to display the result of the query by changing the html property of the div with the class result. And the parameter would be the data fetched from the ajax function:

```
   $(function(){
            $('#inp').keyup(function(){

            var inpval=$('#inp').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: ({p : inpval}),
                url: 'listercust.php',
                success: function(data) {
                     $('.result').html(data);

          }
        });
    });
});
```

**The php file**

First thing that you need to do is to declare all the connections needed to connect to the database. I won’t be discussing it here since its  one of the basics.

Declare a php variable that would receive the value from the ajax function that you have created earlier. Remember that the parameter ‘p’   should match the value that you declared on the ajax function.

```
$name=$_POST['p'];
```

This part of the function:

All you have to do now is to make a query that would use the data inputted by the user:

Then display the fetch values:

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $row['name'];
}

You can decide how your php file should be and how you want to return data from php by communication with my sql.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Jigar. How to do this without using database

Comment: Just curious to why the need for jQuery? It isn't tagged in the question so I'm just wondering why you haven't given an example of pure javascript and ajax....